# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null - mysqli_fetch_array?

Tags: php, mysqli

Im having a trouble with a PHP Login form.

When Username + Password is Correct everything works fine , but when its incorrect it gives an error :

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
> /opt/lampp/htdocs/login/process.php on line 20 Login Failed!

I know is something related with the mysqli_fetch_array but i dont know what.

PHP is last version 7.4.8

```
<?php
// Get values from form in login.php

$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

// To prevent SQL injection
$username = stripcslashes($username);
$password = stripcslashes($password);
// $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
// $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

// Database Connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","1234", "login");

// Query the Db for username
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'")
        or die("Fail to connect to database".mysql_error());
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if ($row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password){
    echo "Login succesfull!";
} else {
    echo "Login Failed!";
}
```

Comment: `or die("Fail to connect to database".mysql_error());` – a) this is not the part where you try to make the database _connection_, and b) you are mixing mysqli and mysql functions here (which you can’t do.)

Comment: You don't check if a row is retrieved, so when the details aren't correct `$row` won't contain an array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning query errors to Exceptions in MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli)

Comment: You shouldn't be storing passwords as plain text, have a read of [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords).  Also learn to use prepared statements.

Comment: `// To prevent SQL injection` – absolutely massively wrong what you are doing there. Go read up on how to do this _properly_; and then go read up on prepared statements, and use those _instead_.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because the `$row` variable initialised as:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

is equal to `null`, when no user matches the provided password and username. The quick fix is to extend the condition for successful login to include a `null` check:

```
if ($row !== null && $row['username'] == $username && $row['password'] == $password) {
    echo "Login succesfull!";
}
```

---

On a side note, know that escaping values using `mysql_real_escape_string` may still not be enough to prevent SQL Injection. Instead, a prepared statement with typed parameters should be used.

Also, storing passwords in a plain text is really not a good idea. It'd be recommended to implement a mechanism using e.g. the [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) functions.

Comment: i will doublecheck the code anyway , thanks everybody for the suggestions !

Comment: @Southsound-dev although this solution would work, please, do consider reading about proper password handling and SQL injection prevention. The current format of your code is prone to several security attacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'")
        or die("Fail to connect to database".mysql_error());
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "Login succesfull!";
} else {
    echo "Login Failed!";
}
```